# Surface area of ellipsoid

Tags: regions, geometry

I think this is a bug

`Area @ Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}]`

returns `Infinity` in Mathematica 11.

Is there a way I can compute the surface area of an ellipsoid in Mathematica?

Comment: 1. This is not a question, and as such not fit for a QA site (unless you rephrase appropriately). 2. Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new question. This is in the tag description.  3. Reporting bugs is good, but they must be reported to Wolfram directly. This is not a Wolfram site.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry, actually I wanted a way to compute the surface area, a workaround. I'll edit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the documentation of `Area`:

> The area of a region of dimension three or higher is $\infty$:

For the surface area you can do:

```
Area @ RegionBoundary @ Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

> `π (2 + 8 Sqrt[2] EllipticE[ArcCos[1/3], 27/32] + Sqrt[2] EllipticF[ArcCos[1/3], 27/32])`

Comment: Also, the "Properties & Relations" section of the documentation for [`Area`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Area.html) states "To get the surface area of a 3D region, use RegionBoundary"

Comment: However, `Area@Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]` gives the correct surface area. Seems inconsistent, @BobHanlon.

Comment: @becko That's because `RegionDimension[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]` is 2, not 3. `Ball` is the equivalent of `Ellipsoid`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Oh, I see.